# Checking/Unchecking the Checkbox using servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page where there are few check-boxes.

```
 <input type = "checkbox" name="facility" value="3 Door cabinet"> 3 door cabinet </input>
 <input type = "checkbox" name="facility" value="Refrigerator" > Refrigerator </input>
 <input type = "checkbox" name="facility" value="Television"> Television </input>
 <input type = "checkbox" name="facility" value="Sofa"> Sofa </input>
```

I want to control checking or unchecking of these check-boxes from a servlet. How to achieve that.

Comment: you mean from java you want to modify html ? or just reading ?

Comment: **control checking or unchecking of these check-boxes from a servlet** I don't get this. more explanation please

Answer (score 1):

The HTML, ie. the checkboxes you see in a browser, is just text received from an HTTP response served by your application. The servlet is no longer interacting with and therefore can't change it directly. HTML is generated server side and rendered (browser display) client side.

If your question was regarding generating the checkboxes checked or unchecked from the server, then you can do something like

```
<input type = "checkbox" <c:if test="${someCondition}">checked</c:if> name="facility" value="Television"> Television </input>
```

using the `core` (`c`) taglibs, where `someCondition` is a request/session/servlet context `boolean` attribute or an expression that evaluates to a `boolean`. If it's `true`, the html generated will be

```
<input type = "checkbox" checked name="facility" value="Television"> Television </input>
```

which will appear on your browser as checked. If the condition is otherwise `false`, it will appear as unchecked, because the body of the `<c:if>` will not be written.

If you want to control the checkboxes some other way on the client side, you will need `javascript`.